# How to add multiple Error message custom validation to client side - asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

using asp.net mvc 5

I have create a Custom conditional validation  which is working perfectly when it is getting posted to controller but not working in client side -

and I am showing the code like below

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)            
            { 
                return View("Index", model);
            }
```

1 .I could not find any way in asp.net mvc which will work without the Jquery code - if you can suggest or show any other way without writing client side code manually that is preferable

2. If its not possible without writing client side code by myself , then how can i send two three error message from server , make it work in the client side

View Model

```
    [ValidateTargetId]     
    public string TargetId{ get; set; }

    [Required]     
    public string DependentProperty{ get; set; }
    public SelectList DependentPropertyDropDownList { get; set; }
```

Custom Validator class

```
public class ValidateTargetIdAttribute : ValidationAttribute , IClientValidatable
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value,
                      ValidationContext validationContext)
        {

            object instance = validationContext.ObjectInstance;
            Type type = instance.GetType();
            PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty("DependentProperty");
            object propertyValue = property.GetValue(instance);

            value = value == null ? "" : value.ToString();

            if (propertyValue == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                switch (propertyValue.ToString().ToUpper())
                {
                    case "Case1":
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
                        {
                            return new 
                        ValidationResult("target id should be blank");
                        }
                        break;
                    case "Case2":
                        if (value.ToString().Trim().Length != 15)
                        {
                            return new ValidationResult("Target Id should have length 15 ");
                        }
                        break;
                    case "Case3":
                        if (value.ToString().Trim().Length != 20)
                        {
                            return new ValidationResult("Target Id Should have length 20");
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
            //for client side
            public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
            {
ModelClientValidationRule mvr = new ModelClientValidationRule();
         mvr.ErrorMessage = "target id should be blank ";
         mvr.ValidationType = "validtarget";
         return new[] { mvr };

        }
    }
```

Jquery

```
$(function() {



    jQuery.validator.addMethod('validtarget', function (value, element, params) {
              //      how to create this logic
       }, '');

       jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('validtarget', function (options) {
          options.rules['validtarget] = {};
          options.messages['validtarget'] = options.message;
       });

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Short answer is you cant. Bit its not clear what your trying do do here - what are you actually trying to validate? And a `ValidationAttribute` has a single responsibility so should not be doing multiple validations

Comment: I'm not understand what you want to do, what belongs to "any method which will work without jQuery"? Your custom validation seems having no sense either (`RequiredAttribute` & `StringLengthAttribute` feels enough to do that).

Comment: It seems you want a conditional validation attribute (based on the value of another property), in which case there are multiple issues with your code and I suggest your read [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2). For example, you do not hard code the 'other property' - you add a parameter for its name in the attributes constructor.

Comment: What I trying to do here is conditional validation based on the property on the DependantProperty . Target id is not required when DependentProperty == Case1 , if its case2 and case3 Have different length .

Comment: just my question is how to create the jquery logic

Comment: Read the link I gave you to understand how to do this correctly, but you can only have one message for one rule

Comment: Sorry but , the requirement is like to send multiple error message in client side. will try to search

Comment: That CANNOT be done using `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`

Comment: Is there any other way of doing it from server side

Comment: Perhaps by making an ajax call (which you could do by using a `RemoteAttribute` for example) to get the relevant error message based on the property values (the `adapters.add` method adds one rule, which can have one message, to the `$.validator`)

Comment: Any example of that please

Comment: Another alternative would be to write additional scripts to modify the rules (refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CLFY9/) for an example, but not sure if that will work with `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` because that plugin initializes the `$.validator`

Comment: [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(vs.98).aspx). In your case you would pass the value of the dropdownlist in the `AdditionalFields` property